# Batch-file to update files from SVN and then run a program

Tags: batch-file, svn, command-line, windows-10

Currently am executing a program from command prompt, basically a Python command, but I want that to be automated so that the program runs the latest version of the files before the program starts.

So current program is run by saying:

```
python c:\program\mysoftwareUI.py
```

mysoftwareUI.py is present in folder that constantly is provided with updates

Now I want to write a batch file with the above command but before that also SVN command that updates the folder before the actual program is run.

How can I do this?

Comment: Copy the script, then run that copy, inside it do the svn update, and then run the first script again.

Comment: Start Notepad (or any other text editor). Write the command for your SVN update. Hit Enter, and write the line for your python script. Save the file with a .bat extension.

Comment: what is the command for SVN update

Answer (score 1):

Create a .bat file script and place it into a directory that is in the PATH variable or the current working directory.

=== doit.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "c:\program"
svn up
python c:\program\mysoftwareUI.py
POPD
EXIT /B
```